# NumPy reduce with an updating parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

Let `X` and `theta` respectively be a `(m,k)` and `(k,1)` shaped `ndarray`. Consider the following code

```
res = np.zeros(theta.shape)
for x_i in X:
    res +=  x_i @ theta
```

The `for` cycle could be rewritten as `res = (X @ theta).sum()`. Now consider this version

```
for x_i in X:
    theta += x_i @ theta
```

is there a way to rewrite it without the `for` cycle, since the `theta` parameter gets updated at every iteration? Maybe using `numpy.ufunc.reduce`?

Comment: The 2nd iteration is `(t+x0.dot(t)) + x1.dot(t + x0.dot(t))`.  It's hard to imagine replacing that anything.